# Chat base session flow not showing flow correctly

Tags: chatbase

I have created some messages in `chatbase` using session_id to divide sessions. However, these are not shown as separate flows. They appear as concatenated flows.

Example messages:

```
[ { api_key: 'xxxx',
    type: 'user',
    user_id: 'Lee',
    time_stamp: 1559340845342,
    platform: 'Chat_Test2',
    session_id: '200',
    message: '_',
    intent: 'choice',
    not_handled: 'false',
    version: '1.1' },
  { api_key: 'xxxx',
    type: 'agent',
    user_id: 'Lee',
    time_stamp: 1559340845341,
    platform: 'Chat_Test2',
    session_id: '200',
    message: 'what_would_you_like',
    version: '1.1' } ]


[ { api_key: 'xxxx',
    type: 'user',
    user_id: 'Lee',
    time_stamp: 1559340848284,
    platform: 'Chat_Test2',
    session_id: '201',
    message: 'hello',
    intent: 'Welcome',
    not_handled: 'false',
    version: '1.1' },
  { api_key: 'xxxx',
    type: 'agent',
    user_id: 'Lee',
    time_stamp: 1559340848283,
    platform: 'Chat_Test2',
    session_id: '201',
    message: 'hello_how_can_I_help',
    version: '1.1' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question and providing the example JSON payload. I see that are numbering your session id's sequentially. You will need to label each utterance with a given session with the same session id. The utterances within each session will then be sorted by timestamp.

If you continue to experience issues, please contact chatbase-support@google.com with your bot's api key and I will be happy to look into your issue directly.

Comment: Hi thanks I  have emailed as requested. The example shows two messages with different session IDs  that are concatenated in the session flow report.